# C# Autofill input box in webbrowser control that has no value attribute

Tags: webbrowser-control, autofill, inputbox

```
<input id="inputID" class="textfield" name="myData" maxLength="5" type="text"       autocomplete="off">
```

I was looking for a way to fill the input box programmatically but there is no value attribute...
I tried element.SetAttribute("value", "blahblah"); 
Any ideas?
It involves C# Windows Forms Webbrowser.
edit: My thanks go to the only one who responded to my post. I've found a better answer for me which is to set the InnerText and then programmatically click the element so it would behave like if I typed something. I am still wandering though whether I could use SetAttribute or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you include the 'runat="server"' attribute in your input tag, then you should be able to access it from the code-behind.  For example:

```
<input id="inputID" class="textfield" name="myData" maxLength="5" type="text" autocomplete="off" runat="server"/>
```

can be accessed as such:

```
inputID.Value = "New Text";
```

Another StackOverflow article explains this: [Accessing HTML Elements in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398021/accessing-html-elements-in-asp-net).

Comment: The Html code is not mine and I do not wish to change it... I was looking for a C# way to deal with it.