# How to use a standard HTML tag in ASPX

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have the following code in HTML:

```
<ul class="ulSpecialty" id="ulSpecialty_selector" runat="server">
    <!--<li class="liSubSpecialty active" data-trait-id="9">
        <a href="test.htm" class="premote trait-link large btn" data-trait-id="9">
            <span class="check"><i class="icon icon-ok"></i></span>
            <span class="name">Cardiology</span>
            <span class="count">6</span>
        </a>
    </li>-->
</ul>
```

How can I use the code-behind to add three of the commented out `LI` inside the `ulSpecialty_selector` `UL` in my page?

I am thinking as long as the `runat="server"` is there, I should be able to access it from the codebehind?

Comment: So you want to have the same markup three times inside `ulSpecialty_selector` element?

Comment: your question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398021/accessing-html-elements-in-asp-net)

Comment: Yes, three in an example but can be more. I would like to use an array and based on the array length run a loop and populate the LI. It won't be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add `<li>` to you `<ul runat="server">` from your code behind you can do this:

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;  

HtmlGenericControl span = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
        span.Attributes.Add("class", "name");
        span.InnerText = "Cardiology";
        //make more spans

        HtmlAnchor a = new HtmlAnchor();
        a.HRef = "test.htm";
        a.Attributes.Add("class", "premote trait-link large btn");
        a.Attributes.Add("data-trait-id", "9");

        HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        //add attributes

        a.Controls.Add(span);
        li.Controls.Add(a);

        ulSpecialty_selector.Controls.Add(li);
```

Cleaner than making a concatenated string!

**UPDATE:**
How to implement this approach with a for loop:

```
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM mytable", "connection string"))
{
    var table = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(table);
}

    foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows){
        HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        li.Attributes.Add("data-trait-id", row["TraitID"].ToString());

        HtmlAnchor a = new HtmlAnchor();
        a.Attributes.Add("data-trait-id", row["TraitID"].ToString());

        HtmlGenericControl span1 = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
        span1.Attributes.Add("class", "name");
        span1.InnerText = row["Name"].ToString();
        a.Controls.Add(span1);

        HtmlGenericControl span2 = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
        span2.Attributes.Add("class", "count");
        span2.InnerText = row["Count"].ToString();
        a.Controls.Add(span2);

        li.Controls.Add(a);
        ulSpecialty_selector.Controls.Add(li);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Would I be able to use FORLOOP to use an Array to populate those data?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Yes you can. I will update my answer with a loop example.

Comment: So from `HtmlGenericControl span = new HtmlGenericControl("span");` and `ulSpecialty_selector.Controls.Add(li);` would be inside the FOR LOOP?

Comment: Yes, if you were adding many `li`'s from your data. You may also need several nested FOR LOOP's. A loop for `li`'s and maybe a loop inside that one for the `span`'s. I will update the example

Comment: I took a second look and you may not need a nested loop... but all really depends how your data is setup. But the fact is that you can have many loops if you need them.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. I think most likely I won't need a second loop.

Comment: How can I convert this line: `DataRow row in dt.Rows` in the foreach statement to use SQL?

Comment: You would have do something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3)

Comment: Also instead of populating a `DataSet` you can just populate a `DataTable`

Comment: I got it to work. To read the data and fill it into the adapter. How can I use your code from above? :)

Comment: Sounds like you need a `SqlConnection` not a `OleDbConnection`

Comment: This is what I have so far: `  using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDataShape;Data Provider=SQLOLEDB;" + "Data Source=wmb;Initial Catalog=DSPCONTENT01;User ID=z;Password=zha1")) {
   OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SHAPE {SELECT * FROM [DSPCONTENT01].[dbo].[BookingTable]} ", connection);

   DataSet dsLocation = new DataSet();
   adapter.Fill(dsLocation, "Customers");
  }`

Comment: I didn't receive any error. I think I can use your code but have to modify the `foreach` statement?

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073382/read-sql-table-into-c-sharp-datatable) post helps

Comment: Couldn't I replace the DataTable into a DataSet? and still use your code?

Comment: You don't need to. A `DataSet` is just a collection of `DataTables`. Since you only need 1 `DataTable` the `DataSet` is unnessecary. I have Updated the post in the **Update** section

Comment: BTW I get the following error: ` System.Web.HttpException: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.BulletedList' does not allow child controls.`

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, by adding `runat="server"` you make the UL available as server-side generic HTML control.

The easiest and most direct way is to assign `innerHTML` property directly in your server-side code:

```
 ulSpecialty_selector.InnerHtml = @"<li class='liSubSpecialty active' data-trait-id='9'>
        <a href='test.htm' class='premote trait-link large btn' data-trait-id='9'>
            <span class='check'><i class='icon icon-ok'></i></span>
            <span class='name'>Cardiology</span>
            <span class='count'>6</span>
        </a>
    </li>";
```

Or you can create individual LI elements in your server-side code (again by creating an HtmlGenericControl control and giving it a tag name of "LI"), specifying all properties of the newly created control and adding it to `.Controls` collection of the UL element above.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest (and the most ugliest) way that answers your question is this:

**Solution 1**

.ASPX file

```
<ul class="ulSpecialty" id="ulSpecialty_selector" runat="server">
</ul>
```

.ASPX.cs file (code behind)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //the ugly way, fastest that answers your question
    TheUglyWay();            
}


private void TheUglyWay()
{
    StringBuilder innerHtml = new StringBuilder();
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        string li = @"
    <li class=""liSubSpecialty active"" data-trait-id=""9"">
        <a href=""test.htm"" class=""premote trait-link large btn"" data-trait-id=""9"">
            <span class=""check""><i class=""icon icon-ok""></i></span>
            <span class=""name"">Cardiology</span>
            <span class=""count"">6</span>
        </a>
    </li>";
        innerHtml.AppendLine(li);
    }

    ulSpecialty_selector.InnerHtml = innerHtml.ToString();
}
```

The above method is by far the baddest thing you can do to solve your problem. Even if it works, the code does not comply with the .NET "way" of writing web applications, it is unmaintainable and ... just ugly :).

There are better ways, here's one of them that uses the Repeater control:

**Solution 2**

.ASPX file

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptSpeciality">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul class="ulSpecialty" id="ulSpecialty_selector">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li class="liSubSpecialty active" data-trait-id="9">
            <a href="test.htm" class="premote trait-link large btn" data-trait-id="9">
                <span class="check"><i class="icon icon-ok"></i></span>
                <span class="name">Cardiology</span>
                <span class="count">6</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

.ASPX.cs file (code behind)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //the better way, using a repeater
    TheBetterWay();
}

private void TheBetterWay()
{
    //bind the repeater to an array of three elements
    rptSpeciality.DataSource = new object[] { null, null, null };
    rptSpeciality.DataBind();
}
```

And of course, using this second solution you can insert data from code behind into the `li` tags using databinding expressions

Comment: No love for `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls` ?

Comment: @zgood I guess there are many ways to satisfy the OPs question. I've added the one that I loved more :)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will try to understand the datasource and databind a bit more and work on that.